# Creating check-boxes out of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array, which is hard-coded for now, and I am trying to create checkboxes based on the array elements that I have.

```js
var features = document.getElementById('features')
var options = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5"]; 
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  x.innerHTML = options[i];
  x.name = options[i];
  features.appendChild(x);
}
```

```html
<label>Select Target</label>
<select name="targetColumn" id="selectTargetOptions">
    <option value="selectcard">Select Target</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<label>All Features:</label>
<div id='features'>
</div>

<br>
<button id="btn-features">Select All</button>

<br><br>

<button id="btn-remove">Remove All</button>
```

I cannot see names of checkboxes as the elements of the array.

Any help please?

Comment: `input` elements cannot have content, so they don't have `innerHTML`. Use `x.value` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkboxes do not automatically add a label next to them. So you need to add the `<label>` tag for each checkbox. In my version of your code here, I have also added the `for` attribute to each label so that clicking the label will toggle it's matching checkbox.

```js
var features = document.getElementById('features')
var options = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5"]; 
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    x.value = options[i];
    x.id = 'checkbox-' + options[i];
    var y = document.createElement('LABEL');
    y.textContent = options[i];
    y.setAttribute('for', x.id);
    features.appendChild(x);
    features.appendChild(y);
}
```

```html
<label>Select Target</label>
<select name="targetColumn" id="selectTargetOptions">
    <option value="selectcard">Select Target</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<label>All Features:</label>
<div id='features'>
</div>

<br>
<button id="btn-features">Select All</button>

<br><br>

<button id="btn-remove">Remove All</button>
```

As suggested by Scott Marcus, you may also choose to wrap your `label` around the checkbox to avoid the need to use the `for` attribute and an `id.` Here is one way to do it:

```js
var features = document.getElementById('features')
var options = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5"]; 
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    x.value = options[i];
    var z = document.createElement('SPAN');
    z.textContent = options[i];
    var y = document.createElement('LABEL');
    y.appendChild(x);
    y.appendChild(z);
    features.appendChild(y);
}
```

```html
<label>Select Target</label>
<select name="targetColumn" id="selectTargetOptions">
    <option value="selectcard">Select Target</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<label>All Features:</label>
<div id='features'>
</div>

<br>
<button id="btn-features">Select All</button>

<br><br>

<button id="btn-remove">Remove All</button>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `.innerHTML` in general as there are security and performance implications to its use, but certainly not when you aren't working with HTML strings. Use `.textContent` instead. Also (just FYI), instead of adding the `for` attribute to a label (which requires than an `id` be added to the checkboxes), you can just wrap the checkbox inside of the label.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have the balls to use `.innerHTML` (at least once), you could simply do it like this: ;-)

```js
var options = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5"]; 
document.getElementById('features').innerHTML=
options.map(o=>'<label><input type="checkbox" name="'+o+'">'+o+'</label>').join(" ");
document.onclick=ev=>{
if (ev.target.tagName==="BUTTON")
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").forEach(c=>c.checked=ev.target.textContent[0]==="S")}
```

```html
<label>Select Target</label>
<select name="targetColumn" id="selectTargetOptions">
    <option value="selectcard">Select Target</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<label>All Features:</label>
<div id='features'>
</div>

<br>
<button id="btn-features">Select All</button>

<br><br>

<button id="btn-remove">Remove All</button>
```